# Core Plot Y axis expandRangeByFactor depends on data?

Tags: iphone, core-plot

i have this problem with gap between Y axis changed when different data is being enter.

First: the third data point is close with other points
[image]

Second: the third data point is slightly further
[image]

Third: the third data point is even further from the other points

[image]

Somehow i change expandRangeByFactor then different kind of gap will appear between each Y axis line.

I wonder how can i have the Y axis gap being fix(not affected by the data that i've put in)?

Thanks

Comment: #define kGapBWLinesY 30

CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0,0);
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
float y = i * kGapBWLinesY;
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, 20, y);
}

Comment: hmm, is that how core plot works? this suggestion is to draw the line manually am i correct?

Comment: yup correct ,so you can implement this in your code of drawing the points and the lines

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the `yRange` of the plot space. Be aware that methods like `-scaleToFitPlots:` and user interaction (scrolling, zooming) can change the ranges, too.